# Is it possible for a thread to select its own unique data from the csv file?

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible for each thread select its own unique value from the csv file, say user1 has account number 202 and the next time it comes in the loop will thread user1 select 202? If not is there any other way out?
I created a thread group and included a http request sampler(login) to read credential.csv to login each user and then another http request sampler to read from accounts.csv to process each unique user specific account. But now since I made the thread run continuously for 5 mins the account numbers got mixed up? Can anyone suggest a way out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an account number must sync up with a specific credential, you should put them in the same CSV file.  Thus, thread1 gets row1 data, thread3 gets rows3 data, etc.

Also, to clarify, a thread only exists for a single loop.  Once you loop through your testplan, thread1 ends and becomes thread X

Answer (score 0):

In your CSV Data set config select sharing mode to current thread instead of all thread.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers, i am still confused, thread execution is not sequential right so even if I change the sharing mode to current will it help? How can i make sure the threads access its own account

Comment: you must do like BlackGaff said if you want to be sure that the right user has the right data. Like thread1 acces row1, user1 should have accountinfo1 in the same row, create 2 variables in your data set to get the value for user and account.

Comment: Thank you BlackGaff, it worked.. :) I used 2 csv files that was the reason the threads acted crazy...

Answer (score 0):

If you want each thread to have its own set of values, then you will need to create a set of files, one for each thread.

For example `test1.csv, test2.csv, ..., testn.csv`.
Use the filename `test${__threadNum}.csv` and set the "Sharing mode" to "Current thread".